# Outputting XML::Twig object contents

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

As an example, I have a Perl XML::Twig object `$xmlDef`, which contains the following:

```
<ROOT>
  <CHILD>
  </CHILD>
</ROOT>
```

It's generated with the following code:

```
    my $parser = XML::Twig->new(
            twig_handlers => {
                ROOT => sub { $xmlDef = $_ }
            },
            pretty_print  => 'indented'
    );
    $parser->parse($xmlStr);
```

When I view `$xmlDef` using `$xmlDef->print`, its contents get properly output to console. When I do `print $xmlDef->text`, nothing gets output. What am I doing wrong by using `->text`?

Comment: try `print $xmlDef->sprint`

Comment: @mirod that seems to work! If I use that method to add `$xmlDef` to another XML object: `$diffXml->insert_new_elt('last_child', $xmlDef->sprint)`, I get output: `<MAIN>**<**<ROOT><CHILD></CHILD></ROOT>**/>**</MAIN>`. How do I get it so it doesn't put the extra **< />** around `$xmlDef` content?

Comment: what are you trying to do? if you are trying to insert the root as an element, then you should not serialize it (through `sprint`) before. Do either `$xmlDef->move( last_child => $diffXml)` or `$xmlDef->clone->paste( last_child => $diffXml)` The second option is probably safer, there were bugs with cutting the root of a tree in older versions of XML::Twig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `text` method returns all the **text content** of the given element. Try adding some text to your XML:

```
<ROOT>
  <CHILD>
    This will be printed.
  </CHILD>
</ROOT>
```

Comment: Ah I see. What if I want to return text + structure? I would like to take `$xmlDef` and insert it into another XML object (e.g. `$diffXml->insert_new_elt('last_child', $xmlDef)`). However, when I do that, I get something along the lines of `<XML::Twig::Elt=HASH(0x152fe5d0)/>` for `$xmlDef` instead of actual content.

Comment: the second argument for `insert_new_elt` is an element name, not an XML string, so you are creating an element with a long (and invalid!) name. Funny enough, this will work in future versions of the module, if the argument looks like XML (ie it starts with a '<'), then it will be parsed. I added this earlier this week to the development version of the module.